# Ошибка 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 870: character maps to <undefined> в условии

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Пишу Бота для ВК Сообщества на Python.

Мне нужно вывести текст из описания одной из команд, но, когда написал:

```
                            if msg_lower == 'личное приветствие - открыть описание':
                                answered = True

                                pgDescription_file = 'Data/pg description.dat'
                                with open(pgDescription_file, 'r') as f:
                                    pgDescription = f.read()

                                time.sleep(0.5)
                                if event.from_chat:
                                    sender(id, pgDescription, '')
                                    chatSender(chat_id, 'Отправлено Вам в ЛС', '')
                                if event.from_user:
                                    sender(id, pgDescription, '')
```

То стало выдавать какую-то ошибку:

`'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 870: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: Файл в кодировке `utf-8`? Операционка - Винда? Тогда добавьте параметр `encoding='utf-8'` при вызове `open()`.

Comment: Да, помогло. Спасибо.
Не знаю почему у меня в последнее время нужно указывать кодировку. Раньше такого не было.
Опубликуйте, как ответ